# how to move an element to the front of a list

Tags: list, racket

i have to make a list in dr.racket which checks whether a number/value is in the list or not and if it is, it should move it to the front. My problem is with the third condition, it should remove the similar value from the list and add it once again to the list using cons but it doesn't work

```
(define (move-to-front lst value)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) #f]
    [(equal? value (first lst)) lst]
    [(equal? value (first(rest lst))) ((remove (first (rest lst)) lst)(cons value lst))]
    [else (move-to-front (rest(rest lst)) value)]))
```